# Diet plan - looking for feedback

Tags: weight-loss, diet

I'm currently working on weight loss.

I'm 25 years old, and work most of the day in the front of the computer(work).

Height: 183cm, weight: 89kg

I'm doing 3x15 pushups and 3x25 crunches every day. In addition, once per week/two weeks I'm running ~7km (1 hour long run). Here's my idea for diet:

Breakfast: 1 vanilla yoghurt, 1 banana, 1 banana (~1hour breaks between each meal)

Midday meal: Cesar salad/chicken with rice (alternately each day)

Supper: 2 sandwitches with white cheese and cucumber

And one (1.5L) bottle of water and couple cups of tea (green, no sugar).

Whad do You think? Is it good to loss weight fast?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the statistics you've given, you're about 6ft weighing 195lbs. You aren't really overweight *(based on recommended height/weight from [this](http://www.healthchecksystems.com/heightweightchart.htm), [this](http://www.calculator.net/ideal-weight-calculator.html), and [this](http://www.healthstatus.com/perl/calculator.cgi) sources )*. My recommendation is that ***rather than focusing on losing weight, focus on building muscles.*** 
 
Based on that, I'll criticize a few things: 
 
First, your breakfast isn't completely balanced. Yogurt should be a snack *(or an addition to a good breakfast)*. There are better low calorie alternatives. Even a wheat-based cereal and skimmed milk should give you a complete diet. Always try to have a ***protein- and fiber-based diet.*** *(Yeah,  I know that yogurt has protein; it just doesn't have enough fiber; also, just yogurt for breakfast? That's not sustainable on the long run)*. ***Get more meal options.***  Also, replace one banana with an apple. Apple has lower calories and provide more benefits than banana. 
 
 
Your lunch and dinner options are alright. You still need more variety though *(unless you're one of those who don't get tired from eating the same thing for a long time).* Also, **drink more water.** 8 cups are recommended daily. Try to get as close to the quota as much as possible. 
 
Second, you need to calculate your BMR *(Basal Metabolism Rate)* to determine how much calories you consume. As long as you consume lower than your BMR *(or increase your daily activities)*, you should lose weight. 
 
Third, your exercise regimen is low; your current exercise choices cannot give you a fast weight loss. Increase the running to twice a week. Increase the push up reps periodically *(weekly, monthly, etc.)* or vary its intensity. Your body'll get used to the same rep/sets and your muscle building will stall. Also, get a pull-up bar and do pull-ups, chin-ups, and/or knee-up daily *(increase their reps as you get stronger)*. Add reverse crunches, standing crunches, and/or planks to your daily routine. 
 
Not afraid of weightlifting? Try [StrongLifts](http://stronglifts.com/) or [Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.com/), or [5-3-1 Wendel's Program](http://www.jimwendler.com/2011/09/531-for-a-beginner/). *(**Spoiler alert:** they are all based on incremental weightlifting :))* 
 
Because you don't have a lot of fat to lose *(to begin with)*, you might not see a huge loss difference on the scale. My advice is for you to **purchase a body fat percentage measurement**. So, even if the scale isn't going down *(or worse, increasing)*, your body fat percentage will constantly reduce. Oh yeah, your pants will start falling too. *You might need to purchase a mirror to start checking out your new body :)*  
 
BTW, don't focus on fast weight loss; focus on a sustainable one....and enjoy exercising; the fat will naturally shed off your body to reveal the muscles they've been hiding for a while. 
 
Hopefully, this rant helps :).

Comment: this answer is awesome, thank You for all the tips!

Comment: @ofcapl I lost weight following similar plan. Weightlifting, cardio, good nutrition. 3 months and counting......and I still love to exercise :).

Comment: In addition or as an alternatives to your current daily exercises.  You could add skipping or squat thrusts.  They would increase your metabolism more than crunches and pressups

Comment: @Tracyat2bactive I've read good things about squat thrusts (a.k.a. burpees) and I'm definitely give them a chance!

Comment: @ofcapl Burpees is awesome *(make sure you do the jumping too)* . If you perform it well constantly *(along with other body exercises)*, your core *(including your lower back)* will be much stronger. Take your time with it; it's painfully enjoyable :).

Comment: @ofcapl - yes, they are good to get your heart rate up and use lots of muscles too.  So good all round

Comment: Why do you assume the OP isn't overweight and doesn't have a lot of fat to lose? At 183cm you could weigh 70kg and have a 30% BFP, or weigh 100kg and have a 10% BFP, the OP did not give us enough information to asses if he has or has not got a lot of fat to lose. At 183cm/89kg the OP could be fine, he could however also be at 40% BFP or at 6%, without solid info from the OP we don't know.

Comment: @Pibara It's not an assumption; it's a fact based on the weight-height recommendation *(links are in the answer)* . Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but its NOT a fact. While there is a statistically important correlation between relative weight and body fat, that correlation is not so strong as to warrant using it as a tool to determine an individual is in the right or wrong zone regarding his/her body fat. As stated, at 183cm/89kg the OP could be at 6% (under-fat), at 15% (OK) or at 40% (obese), nothing the OP has stated tells us he isn't in the overweight or even the obese range with his body fat.

Comment: @Pibara **First,** did you even read any of the sources posted? Did you research to verify their accuracy? Do you even know why such ratios exist? They exist because at a certain age and height *(barring any abnormalities)* , the body's skeletal and muscular structure will normally support a body weight within that range. **Second,** why don't you post a picture of a 18-35 yr old, average, 6ft male who is obese at 195 lbs? **Third** , 15% body fat is **NOT** okay. Normal male body fat % is between 18% and 25%; anything above that is obese. 15% is **fit** .

Comment: @Pibara **Fourth,** since you want **facts,** why don't you ask the OP to measure his body fat %? Scientific **facts** *(based on the information above)* claim that it'll be between 18% and 25%. **Finally,** if it's supported by science, it's a fact, whether you think so or not. And since **it is** supported by science, your opinions *(whether you accept the facts or not)* don't count.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD, Firstm have you ever actually looked at the scientific facts that underly the links you posted? Well, here they are: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b7/Correlation_between_BMI_and_Percent_Body_Fat_for_Men_in_NCHS%27_NHANES_1994_Data.PNG/762px-Correlation_between_BMI_and_Percent_Body_Fat_for_Men_in_NCHS%27_NHANES_1994_Data.PNG Based on these facts you seriously can't claim to be in any way certain that someone with e 26 BMI will have a 18%..25% BFP. Second: You see the two dots at the intersection of the 26 BMI and the 40% BFP?

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD, third: yes it is https://cart.dietpower.com/images/dietpower/Body_Fat_Ranges.gif Fourth: Since I was not the one answering the OP based on dangerous assertions derived from to litle information, its you who should have asked the OP about his body fat prior to answering the question.

Comment: @Pibara Are you serious? The chart you're looking at **is for BMI** . BMI only requires your weight, height, and gender. The links I gave above require those 3 as well as **your age** . Age also affects your metabolism, which is why it's needed. Again, all you need to do is ask the OP his body fat % and see if it doesn't fall within the acceptable standard. You can begin your source-less conviction *if/when* that happens.

Comment: @Pibara This has gone long enough. The science is available, the OP is available, the information is available. You're free to form your opinions. I gave my answer based on the information provided and *its correlation to the available scientific facts* . If it's false, the OP would correct me. *If/when* it happens, I'll be happy to modify my answer. If your goal is to prove my assessment wrong, you've failed. Mainly because you use philosophical conjecture and not available scientific information. Have a great day. :)

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD, how does asking for information now change the fact that you didn't ask the information and simply assumed that information before answering the question? Its a scientific fact that the correlation between weight and body fat is strong enough for population based research but to weak for use on individuals. To make it more concrete, My own progress is evidence of how bad the fit is. A decade ago (early thirties) my BMI/BFP were at 29/39, today I'm at 36/23. It doesn't really matter that much if you add age to the mix, the correlation is simply not strong enough to justify.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD, my goal is not to proof your assessment wrong (it might very well be right) but to make you aware of the fact that you are basing you assessment based on weak correlations that thus create a rather high probability of your assessment being wrong.So where you may be assuming a 95% probability of being correct, the raw data clearly shows that its much closer to 60% or maybe 70% at best.Medical doctors make the assessment like you do as do insurance companies, and as a result skinny-fat people remain in the danger zone while athletes are punished with higher cost for insurance.

Comment: guys/girls this topic wasn't created for such conversations - I've got Your both points of view - In fact, if I wasn't fat, I would not create question about diet and mass reduction ;)